# Output the array such that

Tags: php, html, arrays, algorithm

I am making a program that will output an array in ascending order BUT if there found matching number it will skip that and consider that later.
for example:
array = 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2;
output should be:
array = 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2   //first four sequence number(1,2,3,5) and then repeating number sequenced later.

Here is my code

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $var = $_POST['in'];
  $arr = explode(" ",$var);
  sort($arr);
  $size = sizeof($arr);
  $arr2 = array();
  $cnt=0;
  $k=0;      
  for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)       
  {
   for($j=0;$j<$size;$j++) {
    $k = $j + 1;
    if($arr[$j] < $arr[$k]) {
     $arr2[$j] = $arr[$j];
     array_splice($arr,$j,1);
    }
    if($arr[$j] == $arr[$k]) {
     continue;
     $cnt++;
    }        
    if($cnt==0) {
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  foreach($arr2 as $value) {
   echo " ".$value;
  }
 }
?>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <form method="post">
   <h2>Enter data</h2>
   <input type="text" name="in" placeholder="Enter data with spaces.."/>
   <input type="submit" value="ok" name="submit"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is not working. please correct the code.

Thanks

Comment: what output do you currently get if you put in the same data you gave in your example? P.S. I wouldn't describe your desired result as "ascending order". Instead it appears to be some form of repeating pattern with a set of values in ascending order followed by another set of the same values (if they exist).

Comment: when I input string '1 2 1 3 4 1 2 1' I Get :                                        
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_demo\arr.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_demo\arr.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_demo\arr.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_demo\arr.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_demo\arr.php on line 20
1 2 1 1 3

Comment: Please give your questions a clearer title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array( 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2,2);

$groups = array(array());
foreach($arr as $a) {
    $found = false;
    foreach($groups as &$g) {
        if(in_array($a, $g)) {
            continue;
        }
        $g[] = $a;
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
    if(!$found) {
        $groups[] = array($a);
    }
}

foreach($groups as &$g) {
    sort($g);
}

$result = array();
foreach($groups as &$g) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $g);
}

var_dump($result);
```

it will work for unlimited duplicates

[You can try it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/992e57f1e93d5b4f8187ff7e46b124a576c835dc)

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this:

```
$myArr = [] //with values 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2;
$tmp = $tmp2 = [];
foreach($myArr as $val){
   if(!in_array($val, $tmp)){
       $tmp[] = $val;
   }else{
       $tmp2[] = $val;
   }
}
$finalArr = array_merge($tmp, $tmp2); // your desired output
```

Comment: What if a value appears 3 times or more?

Comment: All unique values will go in array $tmp and rest all will go in tmp2. You only need to merge the two arrays :)